поменять столбец рейтинга и имени bash скрипты
Available commands
cat
grep
sort
uniq
wc
head
tail
New commands ✧˖:
cut
tr
bc
paste
awk

менять столбец баш капец awk
... | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{print $1,$4,$3,$2,$5}'


а можно с тобой связаться?

ты уже и так связан
